# How to get CVPixelBufferRef using texture ID on iOS

Tags: ios, textures

On iOS， there is textureID after openGL processing the Camera raw data.

How to get CVPixelBufferRef data using textureID and the Context ?

Could you help ?

Comment: Please add more explanation and code you tried or have problems with to show your effort. As it is currently written, it is hard to tell what you need (at least for me).

Comment: There is  textureID  after openGL processing the  Camera raw data，how to get CVPixelBufferRef data format using textureID and the Context ?